# Converting DAO Recordset to Disconnected ADO Recordset dbDecimal Issue

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado, dao

In MS Access VBA (2007), I've written the functions below to convert a DAO recordset to a disconnected, in-memory ADO recordset. The problem is that I'm having data type conversion problems on the DAO dbDecimal fields. The problem shows up when I try to insert data from the DAO recordset into the newly created ADO recordset. When I get to the column that is type DAO dbDecimal (ADO adNumeric) I get the following error:

```
Error -2147217887 (80040e21): 
Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.
```

I've looked and the error happens every time it gets to this column. The data contained in this column is simple numbers such as 25, 44, 60, etc.

As you can see below, I've hard-coded my NumericScale and Precision but this doesn't seem to help anything.

```
Public Function ConvertDAORStoADORS(ByRef r1 As DAO.Recordset) As ADODb.Recordset

    If Not r1 Is Nothing Then

        Dim ra As ADODb.Recordset
        Set ra = New ADODb.Recordset

        Dim f1 As DAO.Field, fa As ADODb.Field

        For Each f1 In r1.Fields
            Select Case f1.Type
                Case dbText
                    ra.Fields.Append f1.Name, adVarWChar, f1.Size, adFldIsNullable
                Case dbMemo
                    ra.Fields.Append f1.Name, adLongVarWChar, 10000, adFldIsNullable

                'Here's the problematic one
                Case dbDecimal
                    ra.Fields.Append f1.Name, adNumeric, , adFldIsNullable
                    Set fa = ra.Fields(f1.Name)
                    fa.NumericScale = 19
                    fa.Precision = 4

                Case 9, dbLongBinary, dbAttachment, dbComplexByte, dbComplexInteger, dbComplexLong, dbComplexText, dbComplexSingle, dbComplexDouble, dbComplexGUID, dbComplexDecimal
                    'Unsupported types
                Case Else
                    Debug.Print f1.Name & " " & f1.Type
                    ra.Fields.Append f1.Name, GetADOFieldType(f1.Type), , adFldIsNullable

            End Select
        Next f1
        ra.LockType = adLockPessimistic
        ra.Open
        'On Error Resume Next
        If Not (r1.EOF And r1.BOF) Then
            r1.MoveFirst
            Do Until r1.EOF = True
                ra.AddNew
                For Each f1 In r1.Fields
                    'Error -2147217887 (80040e21) Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value.
                    'Error only occurs on dbDecimal/adNumeric fields
                    ra(f1.Name).value = r1(f1.Name).value
                Next f1
                ra.Update
                r1.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If

        Set ConvertDAORStoADORS = ra
    End If

End Function

Private Function GetADOFieldType(daofieldtype As Integer) As Long
    Select Case daofieldtype
        'Fixed width adWChar does not exist
        Case dbText: GetADOFieldType = adVarWChar
        Case dbMemo: GetADOFieldType = adLongVarWChar
        Case dbByte: GetADOFieldType = adUnsignedTinyInt
        Case dbInteger: GetADOFieldType = adSmallInt
        Case dbLong: GetADOFieldType = adInteger
        Case dbSingle: GetADOFieldType = adSingle
        Case dbDouble: GetADOFieldType = adDouble
        Case dbGUID: GetADOFieldType = adGUID
        Case dbDecimal: GetADOFieldType = adNumeric
        Case dbDate: GetADOFieldType = adDate
        Case dbCurrency: GetADOFieldType = adCurrency
        Case dbBoolean: GetADOFieldType = adBoolean
        Case dbLongBinary: GetADOFieldType = adLongVarBinary
        Case dbBinary: GetADOFieldType = adVarBinary
        Case Else: GetADOFieldType = adVarWChar
    End Select
End Function
```

I am deriving my DAO recordset from an ODBC Linked table which is linked to MS SQL Server 2008. The field is actually a SQL Server Decimal(19,4) data type.

Any ideas how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, but I am not sure why you are not just creating the ADODB recordset from the table and disconnecting it.

```
  Case dbDecimal
      ra.Fields.Append f1.Name, adDecimal, , adFldIsNullable
      Set fa = ra.Fields(f1.Name)
      fa.NumericScale = 19
      fa.Precision = 4
```

Also, why not

```
    Dim ra As New ADODb.Recordset
    ''Set ra = New ADODb.Recordset
```

Comment: It works for me too but later it errors while moving data from the DAO recordset to the newly created ADO recordset. And it always errors out on my decimal columns.

Comment: I mean it does not error out on the decimal columns when I use adDecimal as above, rather than adNumeric, which is what you have in your code.