# Trouble Appending Records to MS Access ADO Recordset - The Records Disappear

Tags: ms-access, vba, ado, ms-access-2013

Using MS Access 2013:

I'm creating a detached ADO recordset to serve as an in-memory write buffer for an application I'm writing. Ordinarily I would use a table/query, but multiple people use the database at the same time. If I wrote these records out to a table, there's a chance that the users would overwrite each other's data.

The ADODB.recordset is defined as a global variable, and initialized with a function. Now, here's the tricky part. I can define the recordset just fine, but when I add the first records, the records "disappear" after being added.

I use a While-Wend loop to add the records. When I break into the middle of that loop, I can move to different records, and debug.print any value I like. But the moment I exit the loop, I lose all the records. Any debug.print command produces "No Current Record" no matter where I move. When I call the global Variable in other functions, I get an empty recordset.

Here's the code:

```
Option Compare Database
'Establish a global recordset variable to be a write buffer
Public gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer As ADODB.Recordset
Option Explicit

Private Function InitWriteBuffer()
Dim strSQL As String
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'These records will form the structure and initial entries of the write buffer
strSQL = "SELECT [#DEFAULT MASTER QUERY].* FROM [#DEFAULT MASTER QUERY] INNER JOIN " & _
"tblBatchCircuitUploadTable ON [#DEFAULT MASTER QUERY].[Install ID] = " & _
"tblBatchCircuitUploadTable.[Install ID] WHERE (((tblBatchCircuitUploadTable.[Install ID]) Is Not Null));"

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)


Set gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer = New ADODB.Recordset

'Create detatched recordset using fields from SQL query
For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
    gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer.Fields.Append rst.Fields(i).Name, adVariant, , adFldMayBeNull
Next

With gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockPessimistic
    .Open
End With


rst.MoveFirst

'Copy values from DAO recordset, one-by-one, into the detatched ADO recordset
While Not rst.EOF
    gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer.AddNew

    'Move through values of current source record, and copy one by one to ADO destination
    For j = 0 To gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer.Fields.Count - 1
        gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer.Fields(j).Value = rst.Fields(j)
    Next

    gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer.Update
    rst.MoveNext
Wend

    'With the following command I receive a "No Current Record" error
    'Moving to first, last, etc in the immediate window all still produce "no current record"
    Debug.Print gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer.Fields(0).Value



'Cleanup
Set rst = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing

End Function
```

Does anyone see anything I'm missing?

Comment: According to [Append Method (ADO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681564(v=vs.85).aspx), *"The following data types are not supported by ADO, and should not be used when appending new fields to a Recordset Object (ADO): adIDispatch, adIUnknown, **adVariant**."*

Comment: I see this as a process than a programming question. Why not use a temp table that snapshots your dataset without user interaction? Why not have the application call the ADO or ODBC recordset at runtime instead of saving in-memory in the backend database? Finally, consider saving the [recordset externally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260348(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: *"Ordinarily I would use a table/query, but multiple people use the database at the same time. If I wrote these records out to a table, there's a chance that the users would overwrite each other's data."* - Not if you've set up your multi-user Access application correctly. Each user **must** have their own local copy of the front-end (user interface), so if the application writes to a local table in the front-end .accdb/.accde file then users will *never* be able to overwrite each other's data.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the feedback! All the points are very good.

In terms of the technical answer, HansUp had it: turns out you can't append an adVariant data type into an ADO recordset. It's not supported. Lame.

So, if you're so inclined as to copy records from a DAO recordset into an ADO recordset in order to detach it, it helps to have a nifty way to map the data types from one into the other as you're creating the ADO recordset.

Here's what I came up with:

```
...
For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
    intDataType = IDS_MapToTypeADO(rst.Fields(i).Type)
    If intDataType = adVarWChar Then
        gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer.Fields.Append rst.Fields(i).Name, intDataType, 50, adFldMayBeNull
    Else
        gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer.Fields.Append rst.Fields(i).Name, intDataType, , adFldMayBeNull
    End If
Next

With gbl_rstADO_WriteBuffer
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockPessimistic
    .Open
End With
...

Private Function IDS_MapToTypeADO(iTypeDB As Integer) As Long

Select Case iTypeDB

    'Fixed width adWChar does not exist
    Case dbText: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adVarWChar
    Case dbMemo: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adLongVarWChar
    Case dbByte: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adUnsignedTinyInt
    Case dbInteger: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adSmallInt
    Case dbLong: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adInteger
    Case dbSingle: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adSingle
    Case dbDouble: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adDouble
    Case dbGUID: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adGUID
    Case dbDecimal: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adNumeric
    Case dbDate: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adDate
    Case dbCurrency: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adCurrency
    Case dbBoolean: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adBoolean
    Case dbLongBinary: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adLongVarBinary
    Case dbBinary: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adVarBinary
    Case Else: IDS_MapToTypeADO = adVarWChar

End Select

End Function
```

This borrows from another StackOverflow solution here:
[Converting DAO Recordset to Disconnected ADO Recordset dbDecimal Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670361/converting-dao-recordset-to-disconnected-ado-recordset-dbdecimal-issue)

Thank you again. I appreciate it!

Comment: I am glad you resolved your issue. But I would be remiss to not implore you to convert your data handling process here. A database like Access should not be making a data request to an application but the other way around. A db must exist and run divorced of any client. It is important to abstract FrontEnd and BackEnd processes. This calling an external recordset in-memory though a neat aspect might be an inefficient use of CPU resources. Consider connecting your app directly to a live temp table data source at runtime. Good luck!